# Deterministic Smart Contracts

Tags: wasm

How does EOS ensure contracts are deterministic? If WASM is used doesn't that mean developer can write non-deterministic contracts which break the network?

---

**Update**

I understand the properties of a pure function, given some input return the same output. This question is about how is determinism enforced? e.g. Are WASM op codes checked? or some other technique etc.

Comment: only deterministic wasm is allowed

Comment: @confused00 how so?

Answer (score 1):

All inputs are based on the shared data on a public ledger. There are no analog or non-deterministic input like the time of a day or random number generator.

- Same inputs
- Same code
- Same results

= deterministic

Comment: What about something like this https://github.com/WebAssembly/design/blob/master/Rationale.md#nan-bit-pattern-nondeterminism?

Comment: https://medium.com/eosio/eosio-dawn-3-0-now-available-49a3b99242d7 - software floating point